# Using Terminal to open a file within a jar file?

Tags: gnome-terminal, zip

How can I open and see within a file within a jar file from within Terminal?

I can use less to print out all the files within the jar file, but how can I open these files?

Comment: Mount the zip file (there are various tools), then open it using `xdg-open`. Remember to unmount afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I use `jar` because it feels more natural, and allows for other operations such as updating contents too. Here are the read commands:

List contents

`jar tf myjar.jar`

Extract contents to pwd

`jar xf myjar.jar`

Extract specific file, creating dirs as required

`jar xf myjar.jar /foo/bar.class`

Extracting the bytecode itself isn't usually terribly useful though. To make sense of it, you need to decompile it into something readable.

There aren't many good java decompilers to choose from. I tend to use [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui), because it's quick and does what I need it to. Frustratingly, its multi-file search functionality never works for me (note that Ctrl+F search-on-the-page is fine). This is no great loss though; you can get it to dump all the sources to disk with Ctrl+Alt+S for perusal with grep/vim/Eclipse etc.

I install it like this:

```
wget http://jd.benow.ca/jd-gui/downloads/jd-gui-0.3.5.linux.i686.tar.gz
tar xzf jd-gui-0.3.5.linux.i686.tar.gz
sudo mv jd-gui /usr/local/bin/
sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/jd-gui
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/jd-gui
```

Using it goes something like this:

```
jd-gui myjar.jar
Ctrl+Alt+S; pick your path & save
Alt+F4
jar xf <path>/myjar.src.zip
```

Note however that JD-GUI has no CLI interface. If you know of a good CLI decompiler, I'd be very interested to hear of it (there is JAD, but AFAIK that only supports Java < 1.5).

Answer (score 4):

Using unzip you can pipe a file from the archive to stdout and then into something else to read it, like:

```
unzip -p /path/to/some.jar path/to/file/inside/jar | less
```

From memory unzip is not installed by default so you might need to:

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

Jeff

Comment: Isn't there a way of opening the file without unzipping it?

Answer (score 1):

jar files are really only zip files you can test this by doing.

```
file foo.jar
```

so to list the files you can simple do.

```
unzip -l foo.jar
```

To access the files just unzip the file with

```
unzip foo.jar
```

If you want to extract only one file then append the files after

```
unzip foo.jar some/path/in/jar/bar.class
```

Make sure to use the full path from -l. And keep in mind it will create the same path locally.

Comment: Isn't there a way of opening the file without unzipping it?

Comment: I'll update the answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

(No rep points, so have to answer to respond to comments by @Kurro)

```
unzip (-p | -c) <jar-file> <file-in-jar>
```

The `-p` and `-c` options extract the file to standard output; `-c` gives an extra 2 lines of data at the beginning (which JAR file and which file within the archive).

I found this extremely convenient for reading the Manifest file or the .xml files.  For the compiled `.class` files, this is useless, but your friend here is `javap`:

```
javap -classpath <jar-file> <fully.qualified.class.name>    # without the .class suffix
```

Some useful options are: `-c` (decompile to Java Assembly), `-private` to also show private fields, and `-verbose` for lots of extra information.  If it's a big file, you may want to pipe the output through `less`.

Answer (score 0):

I've always just defined a function to do this:

```
vijar () 
{ 
    unzip -p $1 $2 | vi -
}
```

To use:

```
vijar jarfilename.jar path/file_to_view
```